# How are runtime errors handled in a C library compiled in C++?

Tags: c++, c, windows, exception

Suppose I have a C library that I'm linking into a C++ program on Windows using Visual Studio. This C library is black box. If a fatal error occurs in this library (such as dereferencing a null), how will this runtime error be handled by the program/OS? I know in C++ that there are null reference exceptions, so you can probably handle such errors with a try/catch, but since this is a C library it won't issue a `throw`, right? So what will happen? The program will terminate, but through what means if not a C++ exception?

Comment: Null reference exceptions in C++? That's not required by the standard, is it? I'm pretty sure that the C++ implementations I've used have all just segfaulted.

Comment: Perhaps some clever use of atexit() could help?  Not sure though.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding, but I thought MSVC issued an exception for dereferencing a null pointer. They call it a "Null reference exception", maybe they don't mean C++ exception here? Also, when I enable debug exceptions (Debug menu >> Exceptions... in visual studio), I get a break when such a dereference of a null pointer happens.

Comment: [NullReferenceException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception.aspx) is a .NET class.  Are you thinking of C++/CLI?  That's not standard C++.

Comment: It's not a C++ exception as far as I know. It's more akin to a signal.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification everyone. It is really hard to tell just from day to day debugging if doing things like dereferencing a null pointer results in an exception in the Microsoft implementation. They appear to behave like exceptions, but are really signals. I need to read up more on signals, and when they are used instead of exceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dereferencing a null pointer in native code will cause an "access violation" on Windows, or a "segmentation fault" on Unix/Linux.  Different names for the same thing.  It's the CPU that detects the error, and it invokes a handler in the operating system, which terminates the process.

Dereferencing a null reference in a VM-based language (e.g. .NET or Java) will throw an exception that you can catch.  That's possible because the VM sits between the program and the CPU, and it can detect the null before trying to *actually* dereference it.

A C library is native code, so you'll get an access violation.  You'd get the same from a true C++ program, which is also compiled to native code.  But if you're using Managed C++ or C++/CLI, those are variants which compile to CIL and run on the .NET runtime, so you get a NullReferenceException in that case.

Comment: "Invalid page fault" dates back to previous century.  It is "access violation" in the Windows NT branch.

Comment: @HansPassant, oops.  :-)  I don't actually use Windows much, and on the rare occasions when something crashes I just see the "encountered a problem and needs to close" dialog, so I didn't notice that the term had changed.  Fixed.

Comment: This is awesome and just what I needed! This explains the details of how such errors (like dereferencing a null pointer) are handled by the implementation, which is what I was asking about in my OP.

Answer (score 6):

You can never "handle" dereferencing a null pointer. Once you do this, your program is no longer in a well-defined state, and there is no way to continue deterministically. The only course of action is to `terminate()`, which the OS will kindly do on your behalf if you have not registered a SIGSEGV handler.

The word "error" has several meanings which could possibly be confusing: On the one hand, a function that is unable to perform its expected task may be said to have encountered an "error", and it would be expected to signal this, either through a suitable return value, or by throwing an exception. This behaviour might better be called a *failure*. A correct program must be prepared to handle all possible ways in which a function may return. On the other hand, there are *programming errors* which simply lead to an wrong or even an ill-formed program. A correct program must never have any programming errors.

For example, `malloc()` may *fail* (if it cannot find enough space), which it signals by returning a null pointer, but your program would be in error if it dereferenced the result of `malloc()` without checking.

You can never "catch" or "handle" *programming errors* with further programming. Instead, a correct program must correctly anticipate and handle all *failure conditions* of component functions, and recursively a correctly written function must always return in a well-defined manner and signal failure appropriately.

Comment: But based on my general debugging, dereferencing a NULL pointer results in an exception. So, with a `catch(...)`, could you not handle it?

Comment: @RobertDailey: No. Exceptions are part of deliberate, **correct** progamming. Dereferencing a null pointer is never correct. I will add another paragraph to the post, stay tuned.

Comment: @RobertDailey: don't confuse C++ exceptions with CPU exceptions. They are two entirely different things.

Comment: Very good answer Kerrek. I'm familiar with general principles and designs concerning exceptions, or "failures" as you called them. It's the "CPU exceptions" I'm not familiar with. The implementation of how programming errors are handled is really what is in question here. While your answer contains some very good information it does not fully answer the main question I had. I still up-voted :)

Answer (score 2):

Support for 'asynchronous' or 'structured' exceptions (such as an invalid memory access) to be caught using the C++ `catch` keyword is an MSVC extension to the C++ language.

You can catch such exceptions even if they originate from a C function as long as you use the correct compiler option, `/EHa`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

You could also choose to use Microsoft's 'structured exception' handling language extension (also available in C), which uses the `__try` and `__except` keywords:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swezty51.aspx

Comment: You stated that exceptions can originate from C functions, but how? C functions are supposed to remain backward compatible with C, which does not support exceptions. Can you explain?

Comment: The exception originates from the Windows operating system and runtime libraries. It is not a C++ exception, like Michael said, it is a "Windows Structured Exception". Those are caught by __try and __except blocks, a Microsoft extension to the C and C++ language. A further Microsoft extension allows C++'s catch to also catch those structured exceptions.